# Do we need to check our sites on Firefox 3.5 and 3.6 both for compatibility?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, cross-platform, sifr

Do we need to check our sites on Firefox 3.5 and 3.6 both for

1. XHTML CSS layout
2. and sIFR and j
3. query/javascript code compatibility?

If my xhtml and css is valid.

If i upgrade my 3.5 to 3.6 then will i have to check site with 3.5 also. or both will render in same way. if 3.6 render differently then i would not upgrade because 3.6 has not much userbase as for now it will take time.

Comment: To the contrary, 4 million people upgraded to 3.5 within 24 hours of release and 3.6 did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If your site is written with valid xhtml and css, there will be little-to-no difference from 3.5 to 3.6. Things like sIFR will only continue to work properly if *their* developers adhered to strict development rules as well, which they generally do.

If you're still concerned, consult the [release notes](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/3.6/releasenotes/).

Answer (score 1):

For any new release of browsers, be it Firefox or others, minor or major revisions, it's always a good practice for web developers/designers to read the release notes.

Firefox/Mozilla has a dedicated site for developers for this as well. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_3.6_for_developers

Based on what you have described, there's shouldn't be any issue, but don't take my words for it :)